# How to troubleshoot reading emails after server upgrade?

Tags: email, mutt, troubleshooting

My host (Kapsi ry internet society) changed the servers, after which I have not been able to read my emails, etc by `mutt` and host's webmail: all mailboxes seems to be empty.
I have done all proposed changes in `mutt` configs, but the problem has persisted now 3 weeks.
I can read no emails by `mutt` anymore.
Everything looks blank.
My host another email frontend also shows all mailbox blank.
The host says that some my mailbox still receives mails.
However, I cannot confirm it because I cannot view them.
I just need to read one email which has pdf attachment.

My host says the following but there is no `$HOME/Maildir`, only `$HOME/mail` and `$HOME/Mail`

> According to procmail, your messages go to ~/Maildir directory.
>
> Use these settings in `$HOME/.muttrc at https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/UseIMAP
>
> Test viewing emails at https://webmail.host.com

My `$HOME/.muttrc`

```
# Automatically log in to this mailbox at startup
set spoolfile="imaps://username:password@mail.host.com/INBOX"
# Define the = shortcut, and the entry point for the folder browser (c?)
set folder="imaps://mail.host.com/INBOX"
set record="=Sent"
set postponed="=Drafts"

set trash="=Trash"

# activate TLS if available on the server
set ssl_starttls=yes
# always use SSL when connecting to a server
set ssl_force_tls=yes
# Don't wait to enter mailbox manually
unset imap_passive
# Automatically poll subscribed mailboxes for new mail (new in 1.5.11)
set imap_check_subscribed
# Reduce polling frequency to a sane level
set mail_check=60
# And poll the current mailbox more often (not needed with IDLE in post 1.5.11)
set timeout=10
# keep a cache of headers for faster loading (1.5.9+?)
set header_cache=~/.hcache
# Display download progress every 5K
set net_inc=5
```

At `$HOME`, I can see where strange many `msg...` files and where I see that at least spam folder's timestamp updates most frequently (even today)

```
drwx------    2 masi   users      10 Jan 22 10:50 mail
drwx------    2 masi   users       2 Feb 13  2012 Mail
-rw-------    1 masi   users   21894 Sep 19  2012 mbox
-rw-------    1 masi   users    1929 Feb 19 11:03 msg.0ZE4C
-rw-------    1 masi   users    2190 Feb  5 07:02 msg.1VGVF
-rw-------    1 masi   users    2362 Jan 26 11:58 msg.2gVHF
-rw-------    1 masi   users    2321 Jan 24 22:20 msg.-3ooE
-rw-------    1 masi   users    3206 Feb 13 19:29 msg.40e4D
-rw-------    1 masi   users 1508290 Mar  5 08:07 .spam
```

Hardware at server: HP DL 360 G7: 2x6-core Xeon @ 3,07 GHz, 144 GB ECC
OS: Linux 3.14.79 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is now resolved. 
The technical support team did this for the resolution

> 1. add to the home directory `.maildir_enable` -file, which tels to the server Devecot about your use of `Maildir` -directory for mails
> 2. fixed `.procmailrc` -file such that spam goes to the right place in the right format - - there was a missing `/` -symbol at the "coordination" row formaatissa
> 3. put all wrongly directed mails to your mailbox